# Implimenting Custom Controller with payment option issues

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, controllers, payment

I'm hoping someone can contribute to my complex issue. We have implemented a custom registration form with the aim of enrolling 'consultants'. Part of this enrollment is to order a special starter product (required). I have implemented a new module and front-end controller to process this request.

Now, I would like to add the payment methods block to my form. so that said user can complete their payment on the same form as their reg details, the registration order is compulsory so doing it the other way around (register customer, create cart, send to checkout) is not going to work, the new user can abort on the checkout, or even go back and add other catalogue items to the order!

So my question in a nutshell is "Can I implement a payment solution on my own front end form??".

In more detail I'd like the user to (1) choose their payment method (derived from Magento's set up payment solutions) then (2) validate this with the registration and (3) process the payment. If all goes well then (4) confirm order and registration.

I'm an advanced programmer and have a good grasp of MVC, however some of Magento's mysticism still illude me! The standard payment/form doesn't work as it requires a logged in user, otherwise just shows a registration form, however If I can inherit, overload or otherwise hack into this and re-use it for my purposes that would be the winning answer!

So:

1. How do I implement my own payment options block on my custom form?
2. After creating the quote/order how do I tell Magento programmatically to 'take payment with details supplied' and handle the response?

Any and all help most welcome! I've burnt some hours trying to achieve this already!

Thanks in advance!

Danny 'Blatant'
Lead Developer @ Cygnus

Comment: What you are requesting to implement is too broad in scope.